# Deploying Django App

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2

I am using a tutorial repo, and now that I want to deploy it to an EC2 instance it is not working
here is the repo, the only thing I added was the ec2-54-197-26-105.compute-1.amazonaws.com

to allowed host. I have left the instance running so you can access it at ec2-54-197-26-105.compute-1.amazonaws.com

REPO https://bitbucket.org/trackstarz/clab
Here is the output

```
KeyError at /accounts/logout
'en-us'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://ec2-54-197-26-105.compute-1.amazonaws.com/accounts/logout
Django Version: 1.11.4
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'en-us'
Exception Location: /home/ubuntu/clab/denv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in reverse_dict, line 335
Python Executable:  /home/ubuntu/clab/denv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/clab',
 '/home/ubuntu/clab/denv/bin',
 '/home/ubuntu/clab/denv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/ubuntu/clab/denv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/ubuntu/clab/denv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ubuntu/clab/denv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/ubuntu/clab/denv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ubuntu/clab/denv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/ubuntu/clab/denv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 5 Aug 2017 01:58:31 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template /home/ubuntu/clab/courses/templates/base.html, error at line 16
en-us
6       <title>{% block title %}Educa{% endblock %}</title>
7       <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
8   </head>
9   <body>
10      <div id="header">
11          <a href="/" class="logo">Educa</a>
12          <ul class="menu">
13              {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
14                  <li><a href="{% url "logout" %}">Sign out</a></li>
15              {% else %}
16          <li><a href="{% url "login" %}">Sign in</a></li>
```

I am not sure where to start here. 
requirement.txt has the following 
django
django-braces
gunicorn

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have an error in your template at line 16. The error is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works at your computer but not the server it's probably due to different versions or missing packages. You can check your python version with `python --version`, and python packages with `pip freeze`.

If it turns out it doesn't work on your computer either, it's a bug in your code. The error message says that there is an KeyError on line 16, which suggest that you didn't assign the name `login` to the URL.

Comment: $ gunicorn educa.wsgi:application    I checked the versions and pip freeze, thank you for that. I basically did the tutorial and set the server up the same so I would have matching versions. I guess when using gunicorn I have to run that command. It is the first time I deployed a Django app, so I used a tutorial to make sure the code would be OK. I will be reading about wsgi and gunicorn to and take a few lynda courses on web servers.

Comment: @eleazarolivera I haven't used gunicorn myself, so I can't help you with that. But if my answer helped you solve the problem, please mark it as accepted. If it is missing a little information that you figured out, please edit it. If it didn't help, but you figured it out on your own, please add an answer describing how you fixed it, and mark it as accepted.